# Report on deleted contributions

Tags: civireport

When contacts are soft deleted, their contributions diseappers from the basic contribution reports.

What is the best solution to be able to display reports of contributions both from active and deleted contacts?

Comment: What is the purpose of the soft delete?  If you still want to be able to include the contributions from these contacts in your reports, then a "soft delete" is possibly not appropriate for them.  There may be a alternative way to achieve your intended outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i can think of is to create a custom report where you could use the criteria you want in the sql queries. i.e. remove the `civicrm_contact.is_deleted = 0` in the `WHERE` clause.

But as mentionned by JoAnne, you may not use the delete appropriately. The soft delete only exist to avoid an entry error. Deletion (even soft delete) should only be used when the contact is a wrongly created contact (duplicate, error while importing, spam).

Anyone with valid contribution, that you want to keep track of, should not be deleted. If it's a duplicate, the contribution will be attached to the other version of the contact so it won't be lost.